# Java get all class and id names from css file

Tags: java, css, scrape

I am trying to get all the classes and ids from a css file in arrays. the arrays should look like this:

```
UsedIds: {"#id1, "#id2" etc.etc.etc.}
UsedClasses: {".class1", ".class2" etc.etc.etc.}
```

how do i get these results without getting the stuff with "." inside the curly braces? I tried to remove every "{code inside}" segment but there are mediaqueries and stuff conflicting with it. My first attempt is below here, but i am not proud of it... It only removes the curly codes, but i'm stuck with this right now. Do  you guys know a easier solution?

```
private void getCssClasses(String fileName) {
    File cssFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner sc;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(cssFile);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String cssLine = sc.nextLine();
            int firstCurly = 0;
            int lastCurly = 0;
            while (cssLine.contains("{")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cssLine.length(); i++) {
                    String character = "" + cssLine.charAt(i);
                    //System.out.println(character);
                    if (character.contains("{")) {
                        //System.out.println("IN");
                        firstCurly = i;
                    }
                    if (character.contains("}")) {
                        if(firstCurly != 0){
                        System.out.println("OUT");
                        lastCurly = i;
                        }
                    }
                    if (firstCurly != 0 && lastCurly != 0) {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cssLine);
                        sb.delete(firstCurly, lastCurly);
                        cssLine = sb.toString();
                        System.out.println("YES");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably want to reuse an existing CSS parser - plenty of resources online.

Comment: A parser gets the files, but i only need all the id and class names from the file which i already fetched.